# Python 3 issues editing test files

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi2, gpio

**In raspbian, I am trying to write a program with Python 3 that logs all motion in a text file.**

PS:
*I am using a PIR sensor hooked up to GPIO 26,
and the text file is named Test.txt*

```
  import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN)
f = open('Test.txt', 'a+')

while True:
    if GPIO.input(26):
        import datetime
        f.write (time.strftime("\n\n%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %p"))
        f.close()
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        time.sleep
```

**My program works fine, until the sensor is triggered a second time. In LXTerminal I am given this error.**

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop $ sudo python MotionSensorLogtest.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "MotionSensorLogtest.py", line 10, in <module>

    f.write (time.strftime("\n\n%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %p"))

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop $
```

> I have been working on this project for quite a while. But, whenever I try to use another post's solution, it either doesn't work, or I can't figure out how to implement it into my program. Please try to understand that I'm just beginning to program, and will probably need one of those "I have no idea what I am doing" explanations.

### Thanks, any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're closing the file in the loop and then trying to write to it again in another iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the file (`f.close()`) after writing to it. You probably want to `flush()` the file so all data will be written at once and nothing will be stored in a buffer (that means, no data will be lost if this script will be suddenly interrupted or Python killed).

By the way, I don't think that you're using `time.sleep` correctly. In the `else` case you should *call* it (use `time.sleep()` -> use parentheses), not just sorta *'mention'* it as you do in your current code.

Comment: @OwenSullivan, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You open the file once in the beginning of your program but then close it every time you try to write to it. Just move the call to `f.close` to after your while loop. If you find that your data isn't making it to the file as often as you expect you might want to add a `flush` call. E.g:

```
f = open(...)

while True:
    if GPIO.input(26):
        import datetime
        f.write (time.strftime("\n\n%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %p"))
        f.flush()
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        time.sleep

f.close()
```

Comment: Calling `f.close()` here doesn't make much sense to me since this loop will run forever if not terminated by some exception, so `f.close()` will never be called.

Comment: @ForceBru You're right in this code example but IMHO having the `close` call around is good practice in case someone changes the code such that the loop can be exited at some point. Also, I wasn't sure if the OP was just presenting a simplification of their actual code.